# Is this true "have we been here yesterday"?

Tags: questions, past-tense

which one is true ?

```
haven't we been here before?
```

AND

```
hadn't we been here before?
```

I ask this question because i heard `haven't we been here before?` from music lyrics.

Isn't 'before' including the past words ?

Comment: How do you define the truth value of a question?

Comment: The option in the title differs from the options in the body of the question.

Comment: Are you asking "Is this true?" or are you intending to ask "Is this question created correctly?"

Comment: I meant 'correctly'. Sorry, bad english

Answer (score -2):

'Before' implies the sense of indefinite past.
So it is necessary to use Present Perfect / in British English/, which is done in the first sentence.
As about Past Perfect there must be some reference to the past moment, before which the action has already finished.
So I think the second sentence is grammatically unacceptable.

Comment: -1 both questions are perfectly grammatical in the proper context.

Comment: ... as in 'he asked hadn't he been here before?

Comment: So, i use present tense when use the word of indefinite past ?

Comment: You would use 'Hadn't we been here before?' when describing a situation in the past when you had asked that question.